# TimeOutException using WebDriverWait with XPATH, ChromeDriver in Python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to retrieve an element from an HTML like this one:

```
<div class="player-header">
    <span class="player-close icon"></span>
    <span id="player-title">My TITLE</span>
</div>
```

Using this XPATH `//span[@id='player-title']` selenium is giving me a `TimeOutExcepetion` but if a use the corresponding CSS or ID selector I will get the WebElement object propely.

Code sample :

```
def find(self, selector, query)->WebElement:
    WebDriverWait(self.browser, self.__WAIT_TIME).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((self.selector, query)))
    return self.browser.find_element(self.selector, query)

find(By.XPATH, "//span[@id='player-title']") # TimeOutException
find(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#player-title") # returns WebElement
find(By.ID, "player-title") # returns WebElement
```

ChromeDriver 2.21, OSX Yosemite, Python 3.5.2,

Comment: Does that happen in firefox too? Thanks.

Comment: @alecxe I am afraid that test in firefox would take a little more research because the page requires silverlight to be installed for any other browser

Comment: did you tried with . initially .//span[@id='player-title']

Comment: @muraliseleniumtrainer the same happens